# How to filter a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to following eloquent db statements in my function. Two read statements on the db.

```php
$groups = V_Member::where('groupadmin', '=', Auth::id())->get();    
$members = V_Member::where([['idgroup', $groupid],['groupadmin', Auth::id()]])->get();
```

First I want to execude the first db statement and then I want  to filter on the collection/variable.
Like this below. But I get an error. What I have to change?

```php
$groups = V_Member::where('groupadmin', '=', Auth::id())->get();
$members = $groups::where(['idgroup', '=', $groupid])->get();
```

This is the error message

> Non-static method Illuminate\Support\Collection::where() should not be called statically

Comment: @Flamms.please add your error also.so that others can identify easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

```
$members = $groups->where('idgroup', $groupid);
```

Operator`=` is not necessary but you can use it where you want. You can also take a look at [where method documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the collection instead of running 2 queries, then you will just need to change:

```
$members = $groups::where(['idgroup', '=', $groupid])->get();
```

to:

```
$members = $groups->where('idgroup', '=', $groupid);
```

For more information you can have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections)

Answer (score 1):

Since $groups is a collection and not a Model Class...

You should use `->where()` instead of `::where()`

Don't confuse collections with eloquent querys, it's a common mistake.

Also, don't confuse methods for building querys with eloquent, with methods for collections, another common mistake.